# How to test a custom processor - Apache Camel Spring Test

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have the following route:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="activemq:topic:inbox" />
            <log message="To: ${in.header.recipients}" />
            <to uri="bean:myLogger" />
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

`bean:myLogger` is my custom processor for formatting the log messages I am getting. The `process` method in my custom processor simply calls a private method that appends the type of message (e.g. CC) and the recipients' email. I am struggling to see how to test the actual resulting logs. I am using `CamelSpringTestSupport`and I am OK when it comes to testing the myLogger endpoint:

```
@Produce(uri = "activemq:topic:inbox")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/main/resources/my-camel-context.xml");
    }

    @Test
        public void testLogEndpoint() throws Exception {
            String body = "Hello World";
            template.sendBody("activemq:topic:inbox", body);
            LOG.info("This is the message body we sent {} ", body);
        }
```

However, I am not really sure how to test the format of the returned logs. Do I send the email of the recipients in a similar fashion as the example above? But then how do I check whether the format is the correct one? I am really looking more for the approach than the actual solution.

Thank you so much for your help,

I.

Answer (score 1):

Make the log formatting in the bean independent on the logger such as another public/package method and then write a plain unit test that tests this method. Then you don't need to use Camel in that test at all.

If you can't do that, then maybe configure the logger to log to a file, and then read that file afterwards and test its logged as you want.

Comment: Hi Claus, thanks for your reply. When you say to make the log formatting in the bean independent on the logger, do you mean to set in the route something similar to: <to uri="bean:myLogger"  method = "methodThatFormatsLogs"/> where methodThatFormatsLogs is the protected/private method in the custom processor formatting the logs? Thanks

Comment: No just have two methods in your bean, one to format the log message, and other to call the first and then log the message. Then you can test the first method, and use the 2nd in the Camel route.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean now. The issue comes from the fact that my "formatting" method is actually a void and when an if condition is met then simply writes LOG.info("{} some text ", arg1, arg2).

Comment: To elaborate on it. My process method in the custom processor already calls the void method that, according to the if condition, writes to the Logger.